# jqueryvalidation does not work with bootstrap select and mask

Tags: jquery, validation, bootstrap-select, maskedinput

I use bootstrap select and input mask plugins on my project. Than I need to use validation. But when I use jqueryvalidation, selectbox and checkobox and radio buttons does not work very well. Only showing error label. I need to selectbox border turn to red when error then turn to green when success.

Checkoboxes are not showing error label. How can I fix this ? realy I search a lot of answer but ı got nothing.

link

```js
    $(".form").validate({
        rules: {
            ad: "required",
            soyad: "required",
            adresbasligi: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            sifre: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },
            adrs: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 30
            },
            cityselect: {
                required: true
            },
            countryselect: {
                required: true
            },
            ceptelefonu: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,
            },
            tcnoarea: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 11,
            },
            eposta: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            topic: {
                required: "#newsletter:checked",
                minlength: 2
            },
            agree: "required"
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group')
                .removeClass('has-success')
                .addClass('has-error');
        },

        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group')
                .removeClass('has-error')
                .addClass('has-success');

        },
        messages: {
            ad: "Lütfen adınızı giriniz",
            soyad: "Lütfen soyadınızı giriniz",
            adrs: "Lütfen bir adres giriniz",
            sifre: {
                required: "Bir şifre belirleyiniz",
                minlength: "Şifre 6 karakterden az olamaz"
            },
            adresbasligi: {
                required: "Adres başlığı giriniz",
                minlength: "Adres başlığı 2 karakterden az olamaz"
            },
            ceptelefonu: {
                required: "Cep telefonu numaranızı giriniz",
                minlength: "Cep telefonu başında 0 olmadan yazılmalıdır"
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            },
            email: "Email adresi hatalı veya girilmemiş.",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        }
    });


    // propose username by combining first- and lastname
    $("#username").focus(function() {
        var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
        var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
        if (firstname && lastname && !this.value) {
            this.value = firstname + "." + lastname;
        }
    });

    //code to hide topic selection, disable for demo
    var newsletter = $("#newsletter");
    // newsletter topics are optional, hide at first
    var inital = newsletter.is(":checked");
    var topics = $("#newsletter_topics")[inital ? "removeClass" : "addClass"]("gray");
    var topicInputs = topics.find("input").attr("disabled", !inital);
    // show when newsletter is checked
    newsletter.click(function() {
        topics[this.checked ? "removeClass" : "addClass"]("gray");
        topicInputs.attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    });

//INPUT MASK BURN here
    jQuery(function($) {
        $.mask.definitions['h'] = '[123456789]';
         $("#ceptelefonu").mask("(h99) 999 99 99");
         $("#tcnoarea").mask("99999999999");
        $("#kkno").mask("9 9 9 9   9 9 9 9   9 9 9 9   9 9 9 9", {
            placeholder: "_ _ _ _   _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _"
        });
        $("#ccvNo").mask("9 9 9");
    });
    
        //Selectpicker Bootstrap
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({});
```

```css
.kocInput{
input.error {
border: 1px solid @indirim-color;
}
input.valid {
border: 1px solid @main-green;
}
label.error {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #f1414d;
  margin-top: -6px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}
}
.citySelect label.error, .countrySelect label.error {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #f1414d;
  margin-top: 4px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.checkboxesError {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.has-error .checkbox,
.has-error .checkbox-inline,
.has-error .control-label,
.has-error .help-block,
.has-error .radio,
.has-error .radio-inline,
.has-error.checkbox label,
.has-error.checkbox-inline label,
.has-error.radio label,
.has-error.radio-inline label {
    color: @indirim-color;
}

.has-error .form-control {
    border-color: @indirim-color;
}
.has-error {
  &::after {
    content: "\ea08";
    font-family: koctasicons;
    color: @indirim-color;
    top: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
.has-success {
  &::after {
    content: "\e91a";
    font-family: koctasicons;
    color: @main-green;
    top: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
.has-success .form-control {
    border-color: @main-green;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li a span.text {
    color: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.has-success .bootstrap-select .btn-default {
    border: 1px solid @main-green;
}

.has-error {
    span {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: @indirim-color;
        margin-top: -6px;
        display: block;
    }
}
.has-success {
    span {
        display: none;
    }
}

.kocInput {
    margin: 6px 0;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 101px;

    label {
        float: left;
        color: @main-color;
    }

    input {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 52px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    hr {
        position: absolute;
        color: black;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #cccccc;
        top: 36px;
        width: 1px;
        left: 41px;
        height: 26px;
    }

    i {
        position: absolute;
        top: 42px;
        left: 15px;
        pointer-events: none;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<form class="form" action="">
          <div class="kocInput form-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="ad">Ad*</label>
              <i class="icon-user"></i>
              <hr>
              <input id="ad" name="ad"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ad" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="kocInput form-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="soyad">Soyad*</label>
              <i class="icon-user"></i>
              <hr>
              <input id="soyad" name="soyad" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Soyad" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="kocInput form-group">
             <label class="control-label" for="eposta">E-Posta*</label>
             <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
             <hr>
             <input id="eposta" name="eposta" title="E-Posta adresi giriniz" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Posta adresinizi giriniz" required/>
         </div>
         <div class="kocInput form-group">
             <label class="control-label" for="ceptelefonu">Cep Telefonu*</label>
             <i class="icon-mobile"></i>
             <hr>
             <input autocomplete="off" id="ceptelefonu" name="ceptelefonu" maxlength="10" class="form-control" placeholder="(___) ___ __ __" required/>
         </div>
         <select id="countryselect" name="countryselect" class="selectpicker" title="Lütfen ilçe seçiniz">
                  <option>Miğfer Dibi</option>
                  <option>Mordor</option>
                  <option>Weathertop</option>
                  <option>Osgiliath</option>
                  <option>Isengard</option>
                  <option>Dol Guldur</option>
                  <option>Rohan</option>
                </select>
          <div class="kocInput form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="sifre">Şifre*</label>
              <i class="icon-key"></i>
              <hr>
              <input id="sifre" name="sifre" title="" type="password" maxlength="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifrenizi giriniz" required/>
          </div>
            <i title="Şifreyi Göster ve Gizle" id="eye" class="icon-eye2"></i>
            <div class="registerchecks">
              <ul>
                <li class="checkbox">
                  <label for="mevzuatcheck">
                  <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="mevzuatcheck"  name="mevzuatcheck">
                    <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon icon-check"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <p>yukarıda  yer alan iletişim bilgilerime reklam, promosyon, vb. ticari elektronik ileti gönderilmesini, bilgilerimin bu amaçla kullanılmasını, saklanmasını ve Koçtaş’ın gönderime ilişkin hizmet aldığı üçüncü
                  kişilerle paylaşılmasını, <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mevzuatmodal">mevzuat kapsamındaki haklarım</a> saklı kalmak kaydı ile kabul ediyorum.</p>
                  </label>
                </li>
                <li class="checkbox">
                  <label for="parocheck">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="parocheck" name="parocheck">
                  <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon icon-check"></i></span>
                  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#parometinmodal">Paro Katılım Metni</a>'ni okudum, onaylıyorum.
                  </label>
                </li>
                <li class="checkbox">
                  <label for="uyelikcheck">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="uyelikcheck" name="uyelikcheck">
                  <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon icon-check"></i></span>
                  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uyeliksozlesmesimodal">Üyelik Sözleşmesi</a>'ni okudum, onaylıyorum.
                  </label>
                </li>
                <li class="checkbox">
                  <label for="parovetanicheck">
                  <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="parovetanicheck" name="parovetanicheck">
                    <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon icon-check"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <p>Paro Programı ve Tanı’ya ait diğer markalar kapsamında Tanı A.Ş. için izin vermeyi kabul ediyorum.</p>
                  </label>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Validate">
         <a href="#" class="btn main-btn">Üye Ol <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </form>
```

Please LOOK THIS here is the worked example : https://jsfiddle.net/f72grt4u/1/

Thank you.